# Why does the stylesCombo display not change when style is removed from p-element?

Tags: javascript, styling, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I have added a specific specific "Email-style" to the styles already present in the styles.js file. When the Style is removed from a selection, the label presented in the stylesCombo-box does not update (It should be displaying the default for when no style is selected: "Style"). When the selection of the editor changes, e.g. when it loses and regains focus, the label changes to the expected default value.
When other styles are removed from a selection, the StylesCombo label updates immediately.
I have encountered this problem both in CKEditor 5 and in the CKEditor 4 dev-branch i pulled from gitLab.

I cannot think of a configuration error i could have made to cause this problem, the only change i made to the dev-branch was adding the style below.

The problem seems to be removing the style from a p-element.

From what i can tell, the problem stems from the fact that no 'selectionChange'-event is fired after when the style is removed.

```
{ name: 'Email Style',
        element: 'p',
        styles: {
            'margin-top':'0',
            'margin-right':'0',
            'margin-left':'0',
            'margin-bottom': '10px',
            'font-family':'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            'font-weight':'normal',
            'padding':'0',
            'text-align':'left',
            'line-height':'1.3',
            'font-size':'14px'
        }
}
```

I would have expected the label to update the same way for all styles and elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try CKEDITOR.stylesSet:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_stylesSet.html

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('myStylesComboBox',[{
  name: 'Email Style',
  element: 'p',
  styles: {
            'margin-top':'0',
            'margin-right':'0',
            'margin-left':'0',
            'margin-bottom': '10px',
            'font-family':'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            'font-weight':'normal',
            'padding':'0',
            'text-align':'left',
            'line-height':'1.3',
            'font-size':'14px',
            'background-color':'yellow'
        }
}]);

  var ContentsCss = ['p{margin-top:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0,margin-bottom: 10px,font-family:\'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif\',font-weight:normal,padding:0,text-align:left,line-height:1.3,font-size:14px,background-color:yellow}'];

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
  stylesSet: 'myStylesComboBox',
  contentsCss: ContentsCss
} );
```

Example:

https://codepen.io/edsonperotoni/pen/JjjZbMB